# How to programmatically create a public google calendar

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-calendar-api

Following piece of code successfully creates a new google calendar.
However, the calendar is set by default as private.
Cannot figure out how to create a new google calendar and set it as public

```
Dim calendar As New CalendarEntry    
calendar.Title.Text = Trim(GoogleRow.Item("CalendarName"))    
calendar.Summary.Text = GoogleRow.Item("Comments")    
calendar.TimeZone = "Europe/Athens"    
calendar.Hidden = False    
myService.Insert(query.Uri, calendar)
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation for the `CalendarEntry` class?

Comment: Probably with [setAccessLevel](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/calendar/CalendarEntry#setAccessLevel(com.google.gdata.data.calendar.AccessLevelProperty))? Wait, that's Java... well, some kind of `AccessLevel` property then?

Comment: Why is this VB.NET code flagged as C#?

Comment: C# was flagged by mistake. Anyway, I think this is not the problem. I really tried everything. Cannot find any method/property to make a calendar public. Anytime I create or re-create a calendar, it is private and then I have to set it as public manually. This can't be. There has to be some solution.